# How to set up input validation in ZF2/Apigility, if rules are field-dependent?

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

There is a class `Item`. It has an attribute `type`, that can be `a`, `b`, or `c`. For all the types there is a common minimal set of attributes / input fields: `type` and other ones. Every type has some further attributes:

```
default set of the common fields
  type
  ...
additional fields in case of type=a
  foo
additional fields in case of type=b
  bar
  baz
additional fields in case of type=c
  bar
  baz
  buz
```

Furthermore the validation rules for `bar` and `bar` are slightly different for the cases `type=b` and `type=c`.

**How to set up the validation in a ZF2/Apigilty application depending on the value of a field (or multiple fields)?** For this concrete case: How to set up the validation depending on the `type`?

---

**UPDATE**

The attribute `type` is an *in*dependent one. That means -- it should *not* become invalid, if the set of the additional fields (`foo`, `bar` etc.) doesn't match to it. (It's `required` and gets [validated agains an array](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.in-array.html) of the allowed values, that's it.)

So, it should work in the opposite direction:

```
IF (type == 'a') {
    proper "required" and validation rules the additional fields
} ELSEIF (type == 'b') {
    proper "required" and validation rules the additional fields
} ELSEIF (type == 'c') {
    proper "required" and validation rules the additional fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `ValidTypeInputFilter` with your custom logic and attach a config that looks something similar like this:

```
array(
    'type' => array(
        'name' => 'type',
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'CustomTypeValidator'
            )
        )
    ),
    'qwer' => array(
        'name' => 'qwer',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
        )
        'validators' => array(
        )
    ),
    'asdf' => array(
        'name' => 'asdf',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
        )
        'validators' => array(
        )
    ),
    'yxcv' => array(
        'name' => 'yxcv',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
        )
        'validators' => array(
        )
    )
)
```

And your custom validator class:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Validator;

class CustomTypeValidator extends AbstractValidator{

    const INVALID_TYPE = 'invalid_type';    

    const NOT_ARRAY = 'not_an_array';    

    protected $messageTemplates = array(
        self::NOT_ARRAY => "Type must be an array",
        self::INVALID_TYPE => "Type must be a, b or c",
    );

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->setValue($value);

        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $this->error(self::NOT_ARRAY);
            return false;
        }

        if(key($value) === 'a'){
            //... validate a
        }

        if(key($value) === 'b'){
            //... validate b
        }

        if(key($value) === 'c'){
            //... validate c
        }

        $this->error(self::INVALID_TYPE);
        return false;
    }
}
```

For validating `a`, `b` and `c` you can also write validator classes and instantiate and use them inside your custom type validator:

```
    if(key($value) === 'a'){
        $validator = new TypeAValidator():
        $valid = $validator->isValid($value['a']);
        return $valid;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm yet not getting your example. Where do you want to validate the fields `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, and `buz` (that should have different rules dependent on the `type` value)?

Comment: Inside your custom validator `CustomTypeValidator`. There you can add all custom logic. You can read more in [the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.writing-validators.html) on how to create a custom validator.

Comment: What might work, is a solution with [`\Zend\Validator\Callback`. But here it's a bit inconvenient: 1. It's not good (for the performance -- if we want to cache configs) to define callbacks in the `module.config.php`, so we have to define all the stuff as a class (or in the `Modle.php`). Well, it's not a big problem. But 2. We have to duplicate a lot of code: For each non-common / type dependent field (`foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `buz`) we need to write a callback with the same logic: `switch ($type) case "a": ... ; "b": ... ; "c": ... ;`.

Comment: @automatix I added more code to my answer. With this example you should be able to manage...

Comment: We seem to misanderstand each other. Maybe my problem explanation is confusing. I've tried to correct it, please see the question **UPDATE**.